Как установить network manager на gentoo
Долго мучался с установкой Network Manager на Gentoo - не работала инструкция на официальном сайте (если конкретно, то не работал флаг euse).
Начал делать по инструкциям на форумах, и все получилось установить.
Прилагаю в ответе свой вариант успешной установки.


emerge --sync
emerge net-misc/networkmanager
nmcli --version
emerge -pv net-misc/networkmanager
emerge -av net-misc/networkmanager
find / -name nmcli 2>/dev/null (должен быть путь /usr/bin и другие)
echo $PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin (эту команду вводить в том случае если нету /usr/bin)
9.nano /etc/portage/package.use/networkmanager
(это вставить:  "net-wireless/wpa_supplicant dbus" )
emerge -av net-misc/networkmanager (после ввода этой команды установка должна пойти)
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager status
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager start
rc-update add NetworkManager default
dmesg | grep NetworkManager
или tail -f /var/log/messages (несколько строк должны появится или нет)
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager restart
/etc/init.d/dbus status
/etc/init.d/dbus start
tail -f /var/log/messages  (несколько строк должны появится точно!)
emerge --update --deep --newuse @world (будет долго обновляться, поэтому лучше запускать на самой виртуалке)
/etc/init.d/NetworkManager restart
/etc/init.d/dbus status
nmcli


Не надо писать в ответе то, что следовало бы добавить в вопрос (я добавил за вас)

@void, так это вроде бы и есть самоответ с решением, т.е. рабочим вариантом установки.

Виноват, не распознал суть вопроса. Спасибо.
